# Make Selected Radio Button Text Bold (UI5)

Tags: sapui5

I am using RadioButton Group in UI5, and my requirement is to make the selected radio button text 'Bold'.
Can this be achieved by css or Formatter.
Thanks

.......code snippet......

```
"": {
    "prefix": "",
    "body": [
        "RadioButtonGroup buttons=\"{oModelSummary>/QuestionSet}\" selectedIndex=\"{oModelSumnary>selectedIn}\" select=\"onSelectRb\" enabled=\"false\">",
        "<buttons>",
        "<RadioButton text=\"{oModelSummary>Name}, formatter:'MyformatterPath'\"/>",
        "</buttons>",
        "</RadioButtonGroup>"
    ],
    "description": ""
}
```

Comment: in formatter you could check the control is selected or not and add a custom class if yes where in change the text to Bold using css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a select event listener to the radiobuttongroup and add a css class to the selected control:

```
onSelectRadioButtonGroupOption: function (oEvent) {
    var aRadioButtons = oEvent.getSource().getButtons();
    // Remove bold from all radiobuttons
    aRadioButtons.forEach(function (oButton) {
        oButton.removeStyleClass("your-bold-css-class");
    });
    // Add bold class to selected radiobutton
    var nSelectedIndex = oEvent.getParameter("selectedIndex");
    aRadioButtons[nSelectedIndex].addStyleClass("your-bold-css-class")
}
```